Data for Augmented solow growth model
I am writing my bachelor thesis currently on the growth determinants of Central and Eastern European nations in the 21st century. In it, want to look at how the neoclassical/Solow growth model fits the data on growth in this region during that time period. What databases/datasets' measures do you recommend to match with the parameters of the model (eg. savings rate, human capital, output elasticity)?
Thank you in advance!

what data did you already look at? What research did you did before coming to this site?

I looked at the investment rates as a % of GDP as well as human capital proxies like life expectancy and mean years of schooling via eurostat. I don't know if they are sufficient to cover these parameters so that is why I am asking if you have any recommendations or experience with such research
